# How does full node verify transaction if all it has bitcoin address and no public key

Tags: bitcoin

If it’s impossible to get public address from bitcoin address. How can a full node performing the transaction verify that the transaction is coming from authorised user.

Comment: Read more about public-key private key-encryption.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. I’m aware of how asymmetric cryptography works, but in this case the node executing the transaction doesn’t have the public key or does it ?

Comment: The bitcoin node does not verify the **USER** because in bitcoin not exist an id wallet or some information to referer at one user, but the bitcoin core using the script language for verifying the transactions is valid for the send bitcoin. So all people that can create the script valid inside the transaction ca be spend the bitcoin, with the signature of the private class is possible to create this world secure

Comment: @Pessy The transaction contains the public key. Check for `scriptPubKey` and `scriptSig`.

Comment: https://youtu.be/bBC-nXj3Ng4

Answer (score 0):

The core of bitcoin is he language, *Bitcoin Script*, this is a language not Turing complete because is without loop.

The node bitcoin doesn't need the public key for spending the bitcoin, but a transaction input have an unlocked script (known as ScriptSig) this transaction can unlock a previous output transaction with have a locked script(Know as Script pubkey), for unlocked the node executed in the stack the ScriptSig + ScrptPubKey, if return true the transaction is spendable otherwise no.

an example

if you have two transaction

```
Input:
Previous tx: f5d8ee39a430901c91a5917b9f2dc19d6d1a0e9cea205b009ca73dd04470b9a6
Index: 0
scriptSig: 304502206e21798a42fae0e854281abd38bacd1aeed3ee3738d9e1446618c4571d10
90db022100e2ac980643b0b82c0e88ffdfec6b64e3e6ba35e7ba5fdd7d5d6cc8d25c6b241501

Output:
Value: 5000000000
scriptPubKey: OP_DUP OP_HASH160 404371705fa9bd789a2fcd52d2c580b65d35549d
OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG
```

How bitcoin execute the script

Complete script

```
304502206e21798a42fae0e854281abd38bacd1aeed3ee3738d9e1446618c4571d10 OP_DUP OP_HASH160 404371705fa9bd789a2fcd52d2c580b65d35549d OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG
```

if you push the script inside [this ide](https://siminchen.github.io/bitcoinIDE/build/editor.html) and run it you can see how bitcoin run the script.

In this example the ide returned false because the transaction output cannot be sent with her input

The ScriptPubKey(most of the time) contains the pubKey

The ScriptSing contains the Signature of the private key

This are all informations for work the simple node bitcoin.

Now I have and question for you.

You say

> impossible to get public address from bitcoin address.

what does it mean?